# How to Get Talend to Keep Table Names in tOracleInput

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

Is there a way to tell Talend not to remove the prefix of column names especially when they are specified in the query to retrieve data from data source and keep the names mentioned in the query itself?

Thanks!

Comment: could you add an example of what is the expected behaviour ? It's hard to see what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the 'guess schema' feature with a query that joins some tables. Further assuming your tables have columns with the same names you run into trouble with the guessed schema. There is no way to have talend use or even know the names of the tables the colums come from, because they are part of a 'projection' and could result from transformation and/or aggregation. Thus, you'll need to help talend guessing the correct schema, which means a) you cant use the `*` to select all columns and b) you should assign each column an alias that hints at the table the column comes from.

So instead of `select * from employee join department on employee.department_id = department.id` you'd have something like `select e.id as emp_id, e.name as emp_name, d.id as department_id, d.name as department_name from employee e join department d on e.department_id = d.id`. The `id` from employee will be `emp_id` in the guessed schema.